# C# the following RegEx too slow on large string

Tags: c#, regex, filter

I am using the following regex to filter large string:

```
(?m)(?(^*(?=.*\\btrue\\b)(?=.*\\ba\\b).*\\r*$)(.*)|(?!))
```

It takes for ever to do so. What am I doing wrong here? is it a problem with my pattern or its a length of string that causes a delay.

Please help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a valid regex, so it might have something to do with it not knowing how to parse it correctly. And how long of a string are you talking?

Comment: My string data contains approximate 1 million characters.Its not that it does not work, only that it takes 9-10 seconds to do it.

Comment: might be way faster to not use regex but simply handle the parse itself manually.

Comment: What is `^*` supposed to be doing? Matching multiple times at the beginn? As @Dispersia pointed out, this regex is invalid.

Comment: I am not well versed with RegEx. So if this RegEx is invalid, I request you guys to provide me with the correct one. The objective is: To get each line which contains word "true" and also "a".

Comment: Thanks Alan. After removing *.  at the beginning, restructured RegEx ^(?=.*\btrue\b)(?=.*\ba\b).*[\r\n]*$  produced the same result in half time. From 31 .5 Seconds it came down to 16.2 Seconds

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fonund this Regex working for multiple words (Here I am using 2 word condition) with AND operator and speed is good compared to my old RegEx which @Dispersia pointed out as wrong RegEx. Strange that even that one worked but taking forever to produce result

```
(?i)(?m)^((?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b)).*[\r\n]*$.
```

Here is the screenshot of the result:
[image]